# brackets not showing after mixin in less

Tags: less, mixins, parentheses

I have been trying the following mixin but when compiled the brackets (parenthesises) for the translateY value don't show and leave a space.

```
// Variables

@slide-up: slide-up;

@verticle: translateY;
@horizontal: translateX;

@positive: 20%;
@negative: -20%;
@zero: 0%;



.transition-slide-up { .transition-(@slide-up, @verticle); }

// Function
.transition-(@type, @axis: translateY(20%)) {

    animation-name: @type;
    -webkit-animation-name: @type; 

    animation-duration: 2s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

    transition-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;   

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    opacity: 1;

    // Transitions
    @-webkit-keyframes @type {
        0% {
            transform: @axis(@positive);    
        } 
        100% {
            transform: @axis(@zero);
        }       
    }

    @keyframes @type {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: @axis(@positive);    
        } 
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: @axis(@zero);
        }  
    }
}
```

This is what I get after being compiled, the brackets are missing please advise;

```
.transition-slide-up {
    animation-name: slide-up;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide-up;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
    0% {
    transform: translateY 20%}
    100% {
    transform: translateY 0;
    }
}
@keyframes slide-up {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY 20%}
    100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't concatenate variables like this (variables are not macros). First of all `@a@b` result is the same as of `@a @b`, secondary `(20%)` alone means a value in arithmetic parens (thus being equal to just `20%`) not CSS function parameter list. In other words if you need concatenate CSS function name with CSS function parameters you'll have to use string-based manupulations: `transform: ~"@{axis}({@positive})";`. And for this particular snippet I'd probably suggest to use just `translate` instead (and set vert. or horz. set by a variable with either `x 0` or `0 y`).

Comment: Also notice that in your code above the default mixin parameter `@axis: translateY(20%)` will result in invalid CSS.